# Can 無理矢理 be used with inanimate objects?

Tags: usage, interpretation

無理矢理 is translated as [forcibly; against one's will](http://tangorin.com/general/%E7%84%A1%E7%90%86%E7%9F%A2%E7%90%86). Does the following sentence mean that "I entered the room against my will" or "I forced myself into the room"?

> 無理矢理に部屋に入った。

In case it means "I forced myself into the room", then 無理矢理 applied to the room. "Room" is an inanimate object. Can 無理矢理 be used with inanimate objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

無理矢理 means *forcibly* and can be safely used with inanimate objects. In that case you can just forget the translation "against one's will". See [examples on ALC](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E7%84%A1%E7%90%86%E3%82%84%E3%82%8A).

And why did you think "無理矢理 applied to the room"? This 無理矢理に modifies 入る because it's a standalone adverb.

Comment: If it is not applied to the room then it applies to the actor and this means that the actor was forced to enter the room, and I thought that the actor forced himself into the room, or 無理矢理 can mean "force oneself to do something"?

Comment: I am not saying that the adverbial modifier 無理矢理 modifies the adverbial modifier 部屋に but it it is indirectly applied to 部屋 or to the subject via predicate 入る. Since nobody is forcing the actor to enter the room then the actor forces his way into the room, meaning the force is applied to the room (its door, window, wall etc.)

Comment: Something/someone is (either physically or mentally) blocking the actor from entering the room in this context, although I don't know what it is exactly. For example you can say 通気口から無理矢理部屋に入る, 警備員を押しのけて無理矢理部屋に入る, 扉の鍵を壊して無理矢理部屋に入る, 彼女の警告を無視して無理矢理部屋に入る, etc.